# IN_ADDR struct strangely defined in android

Tags: c++, android, c, struct, android-ndk

I am trying to compile networking code on android and seeing compilation errors. the struct I am using is is ip_mreq_source which should be defined in header like so:

```
struct ip_mreq_source {
  struct in_addr imr_multiaddr;
  struct in_addr imr_sourceaddr;
  struct in_addr imr_interface;
};
```

Where in_addr should be defined as:

```
typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;
struct in_addr
  {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
  };
```

My detailed error coming out of g++ (GCC 4.4.3) from the Android based compiler:

```
    arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF groupsock/GroupsockHelper.o.d.org -fpic
 -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ 
-D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float 
-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-
limit=64 -Igroupsock/include -Igroupsock/../UsageEnvironment/include -Iandroid-
ndk-r5b/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -Igroupsock -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack 
-DANDROID_NDK -Wall -fexceptions  -O2 -DNDEBUG -g   -Iandroid-8/arch-arm/usr/include -c  
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp -o groupsock/GroupsockHelper.o && rm -f 
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.o.d && mv groupsock/GroupsockHelper.o.d.org 
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.o.d
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp: In function 'Boolean socketJoinGroupSSM(UsageEnvironment&, int, netAddressBits, netAddressBits)':
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp:427: error: request for member 's_addr' in 'imr.ip_mreq_source::imr_multiaddr', which is of non-class type '__u32'
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp:428: error: request for member 's_addr' in 'imr.ip_mreq_source::imr_sourceaddr', which is of non-class type '__u32'
groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp:429: error: request for member 's_addr' in 'imr.ip_mreq_source::imr_interface', which is of non-class type '__u32'
```

I am not sure what is causing the error. Any pointers would be great - no pun intended.
Thanks

Comment: give us the `x` structure, also the concrete error message, pls (: Also, this looks more like C, than C++

Comment: How is "struct x" declared? Presumably member s is not __u32, but Value is.

Comment: If you have /usr/include/netinet/in.h on your machine, struct1 -> ip_mreq, x -> in_addr (takes different forms for multicast address, internet address etc.). I have not been able to find the right declaration for 'x' yet. Still looking :(

Comment: got it!  `struct x { uint32_t s; }`

Comment: Value is of type u_int32_t as well :(....not sure how this is wrong. Although I must say that member 's' is actually of type 'in_addr_t' where: `typedef uint32_t in_addr_t`

Comment: Post the real code. It's going to take a lot of luck for anyone to guess the real problem from this incomplete sample.

Comment: use -E switch to see your code post-preprocessing. This should calrify things...

Comment: Show us line 427 to 429, we need to see the code!, Oh and get rid of all that struct1,2,3,4 and x business, it serves no prupose. If you want to simplify your code, or hide sensitive details that's fine, but then rewrite your piece of code into a simple short piece that is still real code, being vague and ambiguous serves neither us nor yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for everyone's help.
Was able to track down the error to different struct definitions in the versions of the include files for the android g++ compiler I was using.

Turns out the Android platform g++ include files are quite restricted. The definitions of structs in these headers were of the form:

```
struct in_addr
  {
    __u32 s_addr;
  };
```

And:

```
struct ip_mreq_source {
  __u32 imr_multiaddr;
  __u32 in_addr imr_sourceaddr;
  int some_other_var
};
```

So my struct2, struct3 and struct4 were actually __u32 (unsigned ints as defined in asm/types.h) and not even structs in this old version.
To solve the issue, I changed my usage to:

```
struct struct1 st1;
st1.struct2 = Value
```

instead of:

```
struct struct1 st1;
st1.struct2.s = Value;
```

Thanks for leading me the right way though.

;

Answer (score 1):

The following works without a problem, what's your problem?

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;

struct x {
  in_addr_t s;
};

struct foo {
  x a;
  x b;
  x c;
};

int main() {
  uint32_t v = 5;
  foo f;

  f.a.s = v;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to build a net server project written in C++ (and some C) on the Android platform. The g++ compiler is based on gcc4.4.4, but I am not sure if it is heavily stripped down. Your code compiles on standard g++, but using the Android compiler, I get errors: `error: stdint.h: No such file or directory; error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type; error:'in_addr_t' does not name a type; In function 'int main()': 'uint32_t' was not declared in this scope; error:'struct x' has no member named 's'; 'v' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Edited my earlier question with more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code sample you provided. The only sensible explanation that comes to mind is that there's a #define somewhere that conflicts with the name of 'x' and substitutes it to '__u32' (unsigned int?).

You should try to preprocess the offending source file (-E flag for g++) to perform macro expansion and check the definition of 'struct1' in the output.

Comment: Replying below. Sorry for not commenting. Also please refer to my comment in the earlier reply about the compiler I am using. Thanks

Comment: Edited my earlier question with more details. Also, preprocessing with -E returns the structure of struct1 as seen for the struct ip_mreq_source in my edited question. Thanks